# 'Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member' with EntLib 5.0 and .NET 4

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, enterprise-library, ilmerge

I'm using EntLib 5.0 with .NET 4. It was working, but now I've used [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) in order to merge all the dlls in one redistributable .dll. Everything works but EntLib5. When I try to get a logger, I get this exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
  Source=My.Common.Compacted
  TypeName=Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[T](IUnityContainer container, ResolverOverride[] overrides) in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.AddNewExtension[TExtension](IUnityContainer container) in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.AddNewExtensionIfNotPresent[TExtension](IUnityContainer container) in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ContainerModel.Unity.UnityContainerConfigurator..ctor(IUnityContainer container) in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer() in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.SetCurrentContainerIfNotSet() in :line 0
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.get_Current() in :line 0
       at My.Common.Diagnostics.Logger..ctor(Boolean failSilently) in D:\TFS Source\My.COMMON\Framework4.0\My.Common\Diagnostics\Logger.cs:line 35
       at My.Common.Tests.LoggerTest.LoggerTestMethod() in D:\TFS Source\My.COMMON\Framework4.0\My.Common.Tests\LoggerTests.cs:line 21
  InnerException:
```

I've read here in SO that that exception comes from .NET4 because now it's more strict in terms of coding security, but what can I do? download the EntLib 5 source code and fix it myself?

Is there any way to disable that check?

I've merged the files in this order, maybe it's the wrong order:

```
"$(TargetDir)My.Common.dll" 
"$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll" 
"$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll" 
"$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception.dll" 
"$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" 
"$(TargetDir)Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll"
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/245946

Comment: **HOW** was this fixed?? Any ideas?? I'm facing the exact same problem - would **LOVE** to know how this was fixed....

Comment: Read the link. Somebody replied me at that thread and explained that entlib was targeting .net 3.5, and then it is not possible to package it together with .net 4 libraries.